# Remove the Dropbox + Word integration

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, dropbox, microsoft-word-2011

Dropbox has been updated and now it shows a new integration with the Word windows, it adds an icon on the side of the document.

Unfortunately this makes the Word 2011 windows flicker sometimes, and we find it distracting anyway.

**We would like to make this thing disappear** but we haven't found any related options in Dropbox's preferences panel.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dropbox preferences, choose Dropbox badge: Never show.

[image]